# Remove numbers in specific part of string (within parentheses)

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

I have a string **Test123(45)** and I want to remove the numbers within the parenthesis. How would I go about doing that?

So far I have tried the following:

```
string str = "Test123(45)";
string result = Regex.Replace(str, "(\\d)", string.Empty);
```

This however leads to the result **Test()**, when it should be **Test123()**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\d+(?=[^(]*\))
```

Try this.Use with `verbatinum` mode `@`.The lookahead will make sure number have `)` without `(` before it.Replace by `empty string`.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uE3cC4/4

Comment: Thanks alot, this works! Also great website, wasn't aware of this.

Comment: @SomeGuy08: regex101 is not handling .NET-specific regex flavor. Use http://regexstorm.net/tester or http://regexhero.net/tester/

Comment: @SomeGuy08.. I would use ASh/fubo's solution.. it is simplified solution of this solution and also very performant.. (takes very less steps.. also I dont think one should use lookaheads unless there is no actual requirement)

Comment: Also, this regex will capture a number even if it is not inside parentheses: `test 444)`. It will even replace a number if it is followed by letters before a closing round bracket: `test 444string)`. If these cases are OK, then I have no questions. :)

Comment: This Regex is clearly wrong, according to the question. It removes all numbers that are not followed by an open parentheses. The question is about removing numbers within the parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

tis replaces all parenthesis, filled with digits by parenthesis

```
string str = "Test123(45)";
string result = Regex.Replace(str, @"\(\d+\)", "()");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string str = "Test123(45)";
string result = Regex.Replace(str, @"\(\d+\)", "()");
```

Comment: `Regex.Replace(str, @"\(\d+\)", "()")` will work for string in format `(DigitDigitDigit)`; [result `()`];   it will not remove Digits if string in format `(DigitSomethingDigit)`; [result `(DigitSomethingDigit)`]

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this way:

```
 string str = "Test123(45)";
        string[] delimiters ={@"("};;
        string[] split = str.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.None);
        var b=split[0]+"()";
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove a number that is **in fact *inside* parentheses** BUT not the parentheses and keep anything else inside them that is not a number with C# `Regex.Replace` means *matching* all parenthetical substrings with `\([^()]+\)` and then removing all digits inside the `MatchEvaluator`.

Here is a [C# sample program](https://ideone.com/oFdQbu):

```
var str = "Test123(45) and More (5 numbers inside parentheses 123)";
var result = Regex.Replace(str, @"\([^()]+\)", m => Regex.Replace(m.Value, @"\d+", string.Empty));
// => Test123() and More ( numbers inside parentheses )
```

To remove digits that are enclosed in `(` and `)` symbols, the [ASh's `\(\d+\)` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29961437/3832970) will work well: `\(` matches a literal `(`, `\d+` matches 1+ digits, `\)` matches a literal `)`.